# Spark integration with Vertica Failing

Tags: apache-spark, vertica

We are using Vertica Community Edition "vertica_community_edition-11.0.1-0", and are using Spark 3.2, with local[*] master. When we are trying to save data in vertica database using following:

```
member.write()
                .format("com.vertica.spark.datasource.VerticaSource")
                .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
                .option("host", "192.168.1.25")
                .option("port", "5433")
                .option("user", "Fred")
                .option("db", "store")
                .option("password", "password")
                //.option("dbschema", "store")
                .option("table", "Test")
                //      .option("staging_fs_url", "hdfs://172.16.20.17:9820")
                .save();
```

We are getting following exception:

```
com.vertica.spark.util.error.ConnectorException: Fatal error: spark context did not exist
        at com.vertica.spark.datasource.VerticaSource.extractCatalog(VerticaDatasourceV2.scala:76)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.connector.catalog.CatalogV2Util$.getTableProviderCatalog(CatalogV2Util.scala:363)
```

Kindly let know how to solve the exception.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar case. The root cause was that `SparkSession.getActiveSession()` returned `None`, due to that spark session was registered on another thread of the JVM. We could still get to the single session we had using `SparkSession.getDefaultSession()` and manually register it with `SparkSession.SetActiveSession(...)`.

Our case happened in a jupyter kernel where we were using pyspark. 
The workaround code was:

```
sp = sc._jvm.SparkSession.getDefaultSession().get()
sc._jvm.SparkSession.setActiveSession(sp)
```

I can't try scala or java, I suppose it should look like this:

```
SparkSession.setActiveSession(SparkSession.getDefaultSession())
```

Answer (score 0):

vertica doesn't support spark version 3.2 with vertica 11.0 officially. Please find the below documentation link.

https://www.vertica.com/docs/11.0.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SupportedPlatforms/SparkIntegration.htm

Please try using spark connector v2 with the supported version of spark and try running examples from github

https://github.com/vertica/spark-connector/tree/main/examples